# How to automate NanoFramework project modification: download, resource file change, NuGet addition, build, and obtain binaries in .NET Core APP?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, nuget-package, sensors, nanoframework

I'm working on a project where I need to automate the process of modifying a NanoFramework project. I want to create a generic .NET Core solution that can perform the following tasks:

1. Download a base NanoFramework project from a repository (Git or
   similar).
2. Modify the project's resource files, especially the client
   certificate, based on the client's specific needs.
3. Add NuGet packages to the project, as different clients may require
   different packages.
4. Build the project and obtain the binaries (binaries are typically
   firmware images).

Ideally, I'd like to parameterize this process, so I can repeat it for different clients easily.

Example :

I have a base NanoFramework firmware code in a repo with a Resource.resx file containing a client certificate. I need to automate the process of building custom firmware for different devices, each requiring a different client certificate and specific NuGet packages.

For example, I have two devices: ESP32-1 and ESP32-2. ESP32-1 needs a firmware bin with a client certificate change and specific NuGet packages for an ADXL sensor, while ESP32-2 requires a different certificate and NuGet packages for a BMP280 sensor.

How can I create a generic .NET Core solution that, on the fly, modifies the client certificate, adds the necessary NuGet packages, and builds the NanoFramework project, returning the customized firmware bin for each device?

[image]

[image]